# What is the equivalent C# call for the Bitmap class for the BITMAP.IsLoaded call in VB6?

Tags: c#, bitmap, vb6, vb6-migration

I'm converting a legacy program in VB6 to C# .NET Framework 4.8

I have a call as follows in VB6

```
Private m_FingerprintBmp As BITMAP
. . .
Set m_FingerprintBmp = New BITMAP
m_FingerprintBmp.LoadFromByteArray fingerprintByteArray
If m_FingerprintBmp.IsLoaded Then
```

In C# I've converted as follows

```
Bitmap m_FingerprintBmp;
. . .
m_FingerprintBmp = new Bitmap(); // Invalid no default ctor
m_FingerprintBmp.LoadFromByteArray(fingerprintByteArray);
if (m_FingerprintBmp.IsLoaded)
```

But there is no default constructor in .Net for Bitmap class and there is no LoadFromByteArray() method and no IsLoaded property or method for the Bitmap class in C#
What would an equivalent call be in .NET?

[EDIT]  What I have determined is that VB6 supports the concept of a BITMAP instance that doesn't have an image loaded but the .NET Bitmap class does not have a default constructor so it seems any .NET Bitmap instance must contain some form of bitmap image.  So the concept of IsLoaded does not exist for .NET Bitmap class.  So my conclusion is I should use a null reference to indicate an unloaded Bitmap instead of an instance without an image.

Can someone confirm my conclusion is correct?

Comment: I think if it's not `null` should be loaded? How do you load your `Bitmap`?

Comment: See my added EDIT section

Comment: There is no built-in `BITMAP` in VB6. This has to come an external ActiveX DLL/OCX your project is referencing. In VBIDE place the cursor on `LoadFromByteArray` and press `Shift+F2` to locate the definition of the method (and more importantly the **class** you are using).

Comment: @wqw  Thanks! On closer examination of the legacy program you are correct that the BITMAP class is not built it.  It is a class written in VB6 with the source file available in the legacy VB6 project.  So I think my initial attempt at conversion will be to convert the VB6 BITMAP class  to C#.  After that I may look at converting to use of the .NET Bitmap class.

Answer (score 0):

I would use attempt to use `Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(fingerprintByteArray)`. Provided the data works with this class, you should get an `Image` out of it and at that point it's fully loaded.

Note that `Bitmap` you are trying to use is from GDI+ which is not the same as your `BITMAP` in VB6.